# Python: build dictionary from list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

for an assignment I have to build a dictionary where the keys are elements from a list and values are a list with the positions for each element, for example:

```
x = [13, 15, 27, 11, 13, 27]

> dict = {13:[0,4], 15:[1], 27:[2,5], 11:[3]}
```

I can't get the positions from a repeated element in the list.

Comment: I guess you'll have to use a loop or something instead of (most likely) `index()`. Give it a try.

Comment: what if a number would occur more than 2 times in a list?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for i,j in enumerate(x):
    d[j].append(i)
```

Using [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) with the default being empty list and enumerate to provide the index

Answer (score 4):

Consider this answer as a hint:

```
x = [13, 15, 27, 11, 13, 27]
for index, element in enumerate(x):
    print index, element
>>> 0, 13
    1, 15
    2, 27
    3, 11
    4, 13
    5, 27
```